# Resolving git conflicts with SSAS analysis cube projects

Tags: git, merge, ssas

We have an SSAS project in which we're developing a number of cubes. We're finding that when two people work on cubes at the same time, we hit this conflict problem:

```
    <ProjectItem>
<<<<<<< HEAD
      <Name>MyCube.cube</Name>
      <FullPath>MyCube.cube</FullPath>
      <Dependencies>
        <ProjectItem>
          <Name>MyCube.partitions</Name>
          <FullPath>MyCube.partitions</FullPath>
=======
      <Name>TheirCube.cube</Name>
      <FullPath>TheirCube.cube</FullPath>
      <Dependencies>
        <ProjectItem>
          <Name>TheirCube.partitions</Name>
          <FullPath>TheirCube.partitions</FullPath>
>>>>>>> d58147eef253310de9599cfe490eb0cede21c4e9
        </ProjectItem>
      </Dependencies>
    </ProjectItem>
```

One user has merged their branch back into dev, and the third `<ProjectItem>` in their project is `TheirCube`. I finish my cube and goes to merge it back into dev, but in my project, the third `<ProjectItem>` is `MyCube`. This obviously causes a conflict - I can't push my cube into dev without overwriting their cube. The same issue arises when trying to merge another branch into your own, due to how the XML is structured.

How can we resolve this? Will we have to go in and manually edit the XML every time we need to merge?

Comment: what cube you want in dev:  your cube or their cube or both?

Comment: Both `<comment length padding>`

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanna keep both, edit the conflict manually, keep both than merge. Others should pull the new changes.

Now if you don't want both in your local copies, just comment the unneeded one while working and uncomment it  when you are going to commit and push. the other developers should do the same.

Other solutions:

- if changes on this file are unimportant, untrack it in your local copies so you dont have to push anychange no more.

Comment: The manual solution is certainly doable for the .dwproj file, but the .dsv file had around 30-40 places that have to be manually fixed. It's very laborious, slow and error-prone to fix that. Is there something we can be doing - either in git or how we work with SSAS - to not need to do this?

Comment: you can remove `<<<<<<` and `>>>>>` and  `========` by a find and replace strategy , grep and sed may be or any text editor

Comment: Not quite as simple as find & replace - there's missing closing tags that need to be repaired, as those lines match textually and therefore don't conflict, but still need to be duplicated. For eg, in the code above, the `=======` needs to be replaced with `</ProjectItem> </Dependencies> </ProjectItem>` for the XML to remain valid. Other conflicting areas require different strategies in order to keep both and also keep the XML valid. This isn't a simple find & replace problem unfortunately, I suspect it's simply that SSAS's XML format just isn't git-friendly

Comment: Xml Data generally are bad in git, do you really need `.dsv` and `.dsv` to be tracked in git?